# Filter Information form XML format file

Tags: xml

I want filter information from a .xml file, from elements that look like this:

```
XMLElement["div", {"class" -> "art_title linkable"},
  {XMLElement["a", {"shape" -> "rect", "class" -> "ref nowrap", "href" -> "XXXX"},
    {"name"} ]}]
```

I use the following code to filter out the text from the *a* element:

```
Cases[data, 
 XMLElement[
    "div", {"class" -> "art_title linkable"}, {XMLElement[
      "a", {___}, {papername_}]}] :> {papername}, {0, Infinity}];

(* {{"name"}} *)
```

But this does not work if the content of the *a* element is more complicated:

```
XMLElement["div", {"class" -> "art_title linkable"},
  {XMLElement["a", {"shape" -> "rect", "class" -> "ref nowrap", "href" -> "XXXX"},
    {XMLElement["b", {}, {"namepart1"}], "namepart2"} ]}]
```

... which gives the result `{}`.

How can I extract just the text `"namepart1namepart2` in this second case?

Comment: What do you mean "special conditions"? If you just want to handle other XML tags use `Alternatives`, e.g. `XMLElement["a"|"b", _, {papername_}]`

Comment: I reworded the question, hopefully for clarity.  If you disagree, please revert the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define a helper function that extracts the text from inner elements:

```
innerText[list_List] := StringJoin[innerText /@ list]
innerText[XMLElement[_, _, elements_]] := innerText[elements]
innerText[s_String] := s
innerText[_] := ""
```

Then, given:

```
data = ImportString[#, "XML"]& @
"<html><body>
  <div class='art_title linkable'>
    <a shape='rect' class='ref nowrap' href='XXXX'>name</a>
  </div>
  <div class='art_title linkable'>
    <a shape='rect' class='ref nowrap' href='XXXX'><b>namepart1</b>namepart2</a>
  </div>
</body></html>"
```

... we can use `innerText` within `Cases` to obtain:

```
Cases[data
, XMLElement["div", {"class" -> "art_title linkable"}, {XMLElement["a", _, children_]}]
    :> innerText[children]
, {0, Infinity}
]

(* {"name", "namepart1namepart2"} *)
```

Comment: Thank you, your method is well, it helpful.